# Using salt and ice vs cold brine to rapidly cool an object

Tags: thermodynamics

This a question regarding the practicalities of using salt+ice vs just cold brine to cool something in the home (inspired by this recent post: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/116437/cooling-coffee-rapidly-without-dilution). It's similar-ish to this one: [Will ice cream freeze faster with frozen brine or adding salt to ice?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/12449/will-ice-cream-freeze-faster-with-frozen-brine-or-adding-salt-to-ice), but the question does have a key difference from mine I think

A couple answers/comments in the coffee question point out that combining ice+salt to create a slurry can be used to rapidly cool a cup off coffee. The question is, since home freezers are recommended to be set at 0F/-17.8C, and potentially can be set even lower, will this have any practical benefit over just storing a container of brine in the freezer and using it for cooling the coffee? My guess is that at or near -21C, it just doesn't matter anymore, whereas if things were closer to 0C, the ice+salt would see a significant advantage. Assume a sufficient freezer temperature and brine concentration that the brine doesn't actually freeze solid and become inconvenient to use.

Comment: Trying to better understand what's going on by reading more, is the ice absorbing energy to 0C, melting, dissolving the salt, then dropping back down to -20-ish C?

Comment: It can be said, that ice effectively melts at lower temperature in NaCl presence, down to near -20 deg C, depending on ratio ( usually salt:ice 1:3 ). For other relatively available salts, CaCl2 . 6 H2O gives in ratio salt : ice 2 : 1  even near -50 deg C. But it is not very practicar for regular repeated use.

Answer (score 1):

The freezing but liquid concentrated brine may have  better thermal conductivity, so cooling down could be initially faster. But brine would be warming itself up immediately. Ice in the salt and ice slurry would have ( more or less) melt before the resulting brine would start to warm up.

Ice+salt would be warming up slower. Energy needed to melt ice is equal to energy needed to warm water by about 80 Deg C. OTOH, practical manipulation with ice and salt would make total time impractical, compared to brine, or even cold water.

Brine has advantage of reusability and readiness to be used.

IMHO, the most practical is just water bath with cold water, possible continuously replaced. Or metal cup immersed into hot liquid. Brine would bring opportunity of accidental splashing into coffee or other cooled down liquids.

Another way could be cooling by cold water streem via tube/pipe spirale, the best if from a heat conducting metal chemically compatible with the liquid. Stainless steel would be on safe side for acidic fruit tea, where aluminium should not be used.

Comment: But as the ice melts, won't the salt dissolve and change the heat capacity?

Comment: Comment moved to the updated answer.